# progressbar-primefaces3.5 with two different managed beans

Tags: primefaces

Hi I have a xhtml (html1), which has a  save button. The click of this renders method1 of Managedbean1. This method1, inturn called method2 of ManagedBean2 and on success, brings up html1. Is there a way to have a progressbar in html1 and see though both the managedbean actions and display till html2 comes up. So far, all the examples i see have one ui and one managedbean.

@mareckmareck - Thanks for your reply. This is what I am trying to do. - Please see the code excerpts.

### regbudget.xhtml

```
<div id="actionButtonBarNew">
<p:panel styleClass="buttonPanelNew" >
<p:commandButton id="saveBudget" value="Save Budget" type="button" onclick="pbAjax.start();startButton1.disable();" widgetVar="startButton1" />
<p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" value="#{regbudgetMgmtMB.handleBudgetEvent}" ajax="true" labelTemplate="{value}%">
<p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{progressBean.onComplete}"
update="growl" oncomplete="startButton1.enable()"  render="@form"  update="messages,fcotcol" /> />
</p:progressBar>
</p:panel>
</div>
=======================

RegbudgetBean (//regbudgetMgmtMB)
------------------------------  

public void handleBudgetEvent(AjaxBehaviorEvent evt){
// more codee--- code here --
try {
HourAllocationManagedBean hbean = getCurrentInstanceOfHourAlloc();
hbean.calculateHourAlloc();
}

===============================

HourAllocationManagedBean

public void calculateHourAlloc() {
if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
logger.debug("HourAllocationManagedBean: calculateHourAlloc");
}

//more code here---
try{
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/pages/budget/hourAlloc.xhtml");
}
```

====================================================

As you can see, i am in regbudget.xhtml, call handleBudgetEvent in RegbudgetBean , which inturn calls  calculateHourAlloc in HourAllocationManagedBean and displays hourAlloc.xhtml. My requirement is to have the progressbar in regbudget.xhtml to show progress till the houralloc.xhtml is displayed.   Could you please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Show fragment of your code and what you have so far. I'm not sure what you mean by "actions", if you use ajax you can preserve the progressbar easily.

Comment: @mareckmareck - Thanks . I just updated the question with code excerpts. Could you please take a look?. Appreciate your help.

Comment: With this: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/pages/budget/hourAlloc.xhtml");` you reload whole page. To preserve the progressbar you need to save it's state somewhere (database, cookie, session, whatever) and then render it again in the same place, but with progress started at the point it finished before reload.

Comment: @mareckmareck ..Thank you very much for the idea. I have no idea how to go about implementing that, but I would do my bet to figure out how .